# PhpStorm Xdebug : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'docker'

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

After a few days of war with my Docker, Xdebug and PhpStorm I got this problem.

[image: problem screen]

My debug configuration:

[image: configuration]

After I use `curl 127.0.0.1:6080` (because this is my port from docker-compose) there is nothing happens in debug section. I would be thankful for any advices.

```
# nginx
nginx-service:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
        - "6080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./app:/var/www/project
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
        - php74-service
        - mysql8-service
    networks:
        - nginx-php74-mysql8
```

Any my php Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.discover_client_host=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.idekey=docker" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/project

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Answer (score 2):

`pecl install xdebug` installs Xdebug 3, where some of your settings are for Xdebug 2. You should get rid of these:

```
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
```

Please read the [Upgrade Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

The `xdebug.remote_host` setting should now be `xdebug.client_host=192.168.0.1` (if that's the IP address of the host where your **IDE** is listening on).

With docker you do not want the `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` (so set it to `0`).

You can more easily self-diagnose issues by creating a page including `xdebug_info();` (like `phpinfo()`), which will show you all the settings that Xdebug has, which modes are configured, and which hosts (if at all) Xdebug tried to connect to. See also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw) YouTube video explaining how to diagnose issues.

Comment: I took my host address from -> ip route show | awk '/default/ {print $ 3}'
i see in documentation of xdebug they suggest to use netstat tool to find properly port and host. There is something like this: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
but when i set it into configuration i got this error now : Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 0.0.0.0:9003 and this warning: Creating socket for '0.0.0.0:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
Like you said i changed conf to client_port and client_host

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a catch-all IP address, and it is not something you can connect to. You need to find the IP address of your host, and it is well possible that that is `192.168.0.1` for you. `0.0.0.0` is certainly never correct.